# Is #myId the same as id="myId" in HTML?

Tags: html, angular

While taking an angular course I read the following code:

```
<p *ngIf="serverCreated;else noServer">{{serverName}}  {{serverCreationStatus}}</p>
<ng-template #noServer>
  <p>No server was created</p>
</ng-template>
```

I wonder if the expression #noServer is equivalent to the expression id="noServer". Is this way of doing specific to Angular? Is it recommended to use this way of defining the id?

Comment: NO. with `#noServer` you're using a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) that you can get using ViewChild and ViewChildren. id="noServer" only give an attibute to your tag that you can use to style (using .css) or get the htmlElement using javascript with document.getElementById -It's not very desirable when we are using Angular-

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I did a bad assumption here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#noServer` is what's called a template variable. It's **not** the same as an `id` attribute. It allows Angular to reference the element it's placed on, either from within the template:

```html
<div *ngIf="myCondition; else otherDiv"></div>
<div #otherDiv>
```

Or from TypeScript using `@ViewChild`, for example:

```js
@ViewChild('otherDiv') otherDiv: ElementRef
```

For more information, see Angular docs https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables